# check if elements of a range can be moved?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying the range interface of c++20, and I added a constructor that takes a range in my container-like type.

```
class element {
  ...
};

class myclass {
public:
  template <typename Iter>
  myclass(Iter first, Iter last)
    : els(first, last)
  { }

  template <typename Range>
  myclass(Range&& r);

private:
  std::vector<element> els;
};
```

The iterator-pair version is quite easy. In `els_(first, last);`, it copies the elements if Iter is a normal iterator, it moves the elements if Iter is a movable iterator such as `std::move_iterator<>`. It's callers responsibility to explicitly give the movable iterators if the caller wants the elements moved.

In the range version, however, although I can check if the range itself is given in a rvalue reference or lvalue reference, it doesn't help checking if the element can be moved or not.

Let's say that we have a range maker, `make_range()`, which takes a container and returns a proxy instance which complies the range concept. In the following code, `Range` of the constructor is an rvalue reference in both cases but obviously the elements should not be moved in the second case.

```
std::list<element> list_of_elements{...};
myclass c(std::move(list_of_elements)); // should be moved

std::list<element> list_of_elements_to_be_reused{...};
myclass c(make_range(list_of_elements_to_be_reused)); // should not be moved
```

How can I check if the given range is for copying for moving?

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You trust the iterator returned by `std::ranges::begin`, same as you would trust the iterator `Iter` to do the right thing. Your second constructor can just delegate:

```
template <std::ranges::Range Range> // Constraints checked with the library concept
myclass(Range&& r) : myclass(std::ranges::begin(std::move(r)), std::ranges::end(std::move(r)))
{}
```

The default behavior *is* to copy, which is sensible. But since `std::ranges::begin` is a customization point object, it can pick up on user defined `begin` overloads by ADL. For a user defined type, this setup:

```
namespace myns {
    class myclass { /* ... */ };
    auto begin(std::vector<myclass>&& v) { return std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()); }
    auto end(std::vector<myclass>&& v) { /* ... * }
}
```

Will make `std::ranges::begin` call `myns::begin` when the class constructor is passed an rvalue vector. It is the user defined type that controls the behavior, which is good.

Comment: Will `myclass c(std::vector<element>{...});` copy the elements? or move them?

Comment: @InbaeJeong - By default it copies. And it's not entirely unreasonable. The vector may be trivially movable, but it doesn't automatically translate to the element types. On the other hand, since `std::ranges::begin` is a customization point object, you can change that. A moment.

Comment: `myns::begin` might work but it still needs to be provided for all the possible types of containers, since it can't be templatized because of the same reason with my post. Then I see no reason to use ranges.

Comment: @inbae - Who said it can't be a template? It can. Just needs to be made a better match in partial ordering compared to the catchall deleted overload provided by the standard library. That's not impossible.